# Web worker memory leak when using transferables

Tags: google-chrome, electron, chromium, web-worker, worker

I'm sending a canvas image as a bitmap to a web worker, which converts it to a blob and sends it back. Including the ImageBitmap and the returning ArrayBuffer in the postMessage transferables seems to be the best practice for better performance, but since Chromium version M93 or M92 doing this is causing a huge memory leak. I do this repeatedly, but waiting until the worker is done. Was fine until ElectronJS 13 (Chrome 91).

In a nutshell, the main process converts a canvas to a bitmap and sends it to the worker:

```js
createImageBitmap(canvas).then(bitmap => {
    worker.postMessage(bitmap, [bitmap]);
});
```

And the worker creates the blob and sends it back:

```js
worker.onmessage = function ({ data }) {
    ctx.transferFromImageBitmap(data);
    canvas.convertToBlob().then(blob => {
        blob.arrayBuffer().then(arrBuf => {
            worker.postMessage(arrBuf, [arrBuf]);
        });
    });
};
```

This is simplified. A more complete example can be found in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1eqkfngc/ (In the fiddle, the memory goes back down eventually, on Electron it does not)

Removing the array of transferables resolves the memory issue, but is less performant in theory.

Should I be doing something different or is this a bug in Chrome? I have filed a bug report.

Comment: And when you force a Garbage Collection it doesn't go down? There is nothing in your code that should retain anything in memory, so that would be a browser bug indeed.

Comment: How would you force a garbage collection? I have tried things like bitmap.close(), bitmap = null, etc. to no avail.

Comment: In a browser that would be through the dev-tools > Memory > Collect garbage (trash-bin icon). But in Electron I'm not sure.

Comment: And indeed, you don't need to explicitly close the ImageBitmap here, the BitmapRendingContext is supposed to take care of it.

Comment: @Kaiido, indeed, some of the memory is cleared when forcing a Garbage Collection. Performance is still not great, though, compared to previous Chrome versions. I believe I have narrowed this down to a change between Chrome 92.0.4501.0 and 92.0.4502.0. Here's the bug report in case it helps anyone connect ideas: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1424257

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed around Chrome version 115.0.5780.0 and Electron version 26